# Need to extract from string together with line reference number

Tags: ruby, string

My problem is I have a very large file, an example:

```
f = %q(1:9- The cost of\n  
51:10- The beams cost so much\n  
41:11- Should we buy more beams\n  
21:12- Why buy more}
```

What I need to do is, as an example, is extract every beams word from any line that contains that particular word. But each beams word must come with the reference for the line it comes from, like this:

```
51:10 beams\n  
41:11 beams\n
```

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\d{2,2}:\d{2,2})-.*?(beams)/
```

The first capture will contain the line reference and the second the word beams

Comment: Thanks ennuikiller and Kimmmo both work great but, sorry, my fault, I should have put a "beams" in the first line 1:9 How would I alter the {2} if beams is in 1:9 - which has only one numeral either side of the colon (or at times 3 numbers either side of the colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract using `scan`:

```
f.scan(/^(\d+\:\d+).+?(beams)/)
=> [["51:10", "beams"], ["41:11", "beams"]]
```

And for the output:

```
f.scan(/^(\d+\:\d+).+?(beams)/).each do |pair| 
  puts pair.join(" ")
end
=>
51:10 beams
41:11 beams
```